# How do you get MySql db data, or XML data 2 show inside a Div?

Tags: mysql, xml, database, html, catalog

How can you populate data from an external text document, xml sheet or php MySql db?  I'm using a MacPro, Dreamweaver CS4, Xampp  & Php MySql Database. I'm open to suggestions as to what would be the easiest method for my setup.

example:

**Text Doc:** Where I would type the info. to be placed into the divs?

```
Item 1

id_1: 123456

pic_1: /imgs/phones/iphone4.jpg

Title_1: iphone4

price_1: $500

description_1: The New iPhone 4 now available for only $500

releasedate_1: 3/29/2011
```

**Divs** to be populated with corresponding data from txt sheet or xml sheet.

```
<div id="item_1">

<div id="pic_1"></div>

<div id="Title_1"></div>

<div id="price_1"></div>

<div id="description_1"></div>

<div id="id_1"></div>

<div id="releasedate_1"></div>

</div>
```

only reason I'm asking is because there will be many items listed on the page and of course I would like to make the process easier for editing the items.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to decide how exactly you want to do this. XML or MySQL for housing the data is the most natural. Displaying the data can be done by JavaScript or PHP. It is pretty simple once you know what you are trying to accomplish and can articulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've made your connection, you could do something like this..

```
&lt;?php

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items");

while($result=mysql_fetch_array($sql))

{

     $pic = $result['pic_1'];
     echo "<div><img src='$pic'/></div>";
}

?&gt;
```

Comment: okay that makes sense, so for the php code where the `code`{ $pic = $result['pic_1'];
     echo "<div><img src='$pic'/></div>"; }`code` would I just ad the `code`['pic_1' 'pic_2' 'pic_3']`code` and so on?

Comment: and for the echo would i have to name the div like this? `code` "<div id="pic_1"><img src='$pic'/></div>"; `code` so it knows which div to add the corresponding pic to? and the same for the 2nd 3rd and 4th divs and so on?  I guess what I'm trying to say is, I see how that would work for one div but would I have to keep writing that php code for each and every div or is it smart enough to populate all the divs in one shot, if that makes any sense?